# cannot read property of top with offset().top - x

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a strange bug that I cannot uncover. I found a similar question but it wasn't similar to my bug.

I have a simple JS function that will animate a scroll when clicking a href link. It works totally fine within this js fiddle, but it doesn't seem to work on this page (even though it's identical) and I cannot find the underlying issue.

https://www.wolfandgrizzly.com/pages/instructions

It occurs when you select a language.

```js
  var e = window.innerWidth;
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href^="#"]', function(s) {
  console.log($.attr(this, "href"));
   s.preventDefault(), e >= 770 ? $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top - 48
   
   }, 500) : $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top - 100
   }, 500)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:1000px;"><a href="#clickMe">ClickMe</a></div>
<div id="clickMe">
```

Comment: On that page there is nothing with id="German". When you click on a[href="#German"] the browser by default scrolls (ugly, non animated) to the element with ID = whatever_comes_after_hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are using `#clickMe` and `id="clickMe"` on your actual webpage, you are using `#French` and `name="French"`.  The `#` selector looks for elements with the `id` attribute.  You are not using `id` on your page.

You can change your html to use `id`, or you can change your `scrollTop` logic to select by `name="French"`

Answer (score 2):

On that page there is nothing with id="German". When you click on a[href="#German"] the browser by default scrolls (ugly, non animated) to the element with ID = whatever_comes_after_hash. Your function overrides that behaviour with a nice smooth scroll down... But it still looks after an element with `id="whatever_comes_after_hash"` in `a href="#whatever_comes_after_hash"`

Therefore the solution you need, is to add IDs to the elements on that page, and it should work perfectly fine.

```js
var e = window.innerWidth;
  $(document).on("click", 'a[href^="#"]', function(s) {
  console.log($.attr(this, "href"));
   s.preventDefault(), e >= 770 ? $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top - 48
   
   }, 500) : $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top - 100
   }, 500)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#id_of_target_element">ClickMe</a>

<div style='height: 1000px; background-color: red;'></div>
<div id="id_of_target_element">target element</div>
<div style='height: 1000px; background-color: blue;'></div>
```